# What are these functions doing in order to create a dictionary?

Tags: python, function, dictionary

I just started learning python and classes is not my strong point at all, i was trying to understand how a dict is created namely the self = dict() part and the self[key]= value

```
> class Website(dict):
    def __init__(self):
      self = dict()
    def add(self, key, value):
      self[key] = value
  New_dict.add(webuser,FinalPass)
```

Comment: `self = dict()` does nothing. Reassigning the local variable `self` to a new object does nothing to the calling context. The canonical way to call the base class' initiailizer is `super().__init__()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dict()` creates and empty dictionary.

`self` is the instance object, the `Website` object.

Once those are done, the second function takes that dictionary object and assigns a value to a given key, just as with any other dictionary.

```
>>> class Website(dict):
...     def __init__(self):
...       pass 
...       # self = dict()
...     def add(self, key, value):
...       self[key] = value
... 
>>> w = Website()
>>> w
{}
>>> w.add("first", 17)
>>> w
{'first': 17}
```

Comment: This would still work without the line `self = dict()`, as this doesn't do anything (except create an empty `dict` which is immediately discarded). And is perhaps misleading.

Comment: First I did the head-slap, then I reran it as above.  The `self` that is now commented out is a local variable that gets discarded upon completion of `__init__`.

Comment: Thank you im going to mess with classes a bit more i really need a lot more training on those

Comment: Excellent!  That's what we want to see: SO gets you over one small problem, and you run free over the tutorials.